# Change Variable values based on branch in AzureDevOps CI Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

In AzureDevOps How to change the value of the variable based on the branch the CI pipeline is running for.

Like for `dev` branch `var-value` = "**develop**" where as for `master` branch `var-value` = "**master**".

Comment: Have you tried doing it in a PowerShell task?

Comment: Just want to check whether Shayki's script could help you achieve change variable which based on the branches associate with CI? Appreciate for [marking it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it is work for you. Or leave comment below if you still has any issue or puzzle:-)

Comment: have not tested Shayki's script. Instead, I used Multibranch pipeline in azure Devops with Variable groups for changing variable values according to the branch name

Answer (score 7):

You can use a simple PowerShell script that checks the [pre-defined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) variable `Build.SourceBranchName` and set the variable value:

```
$branch = "$(Build.SourceBranchName)"
if($branch -eq "master")
{
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=var-value]master"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=var-value]develop"
}
```